# How can I benchmark the bandwidth and latency of the connection between my PC and wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, latency, benchmarking

It seems like this should be easy in theory, especially the latency part. Just spam the router with packets and see how many get returned and how long they take. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows has ping and other OS's have similar functions. Just look into how you can change the size of a package to use for proper measurement. A larger packet can better measure the stability/bandwidth of a connection whereas a low package can measure the latency better.

Comment: @LPChip, so for bandwidth, should I just keep adding more size to the packets and then define the bandwidth as the limit where packets start getting dropped?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that you will not get a perfect result, but only an estimate. Too many factors in play and Ping just isn't the tool for that. Copying a file from one pc to another and measuring its speed is a better way.

Comment: @LPChip, How should I send a file to another computer in my LAN over the wireless router?

Comment: Share a folder, then copy a file to the other computer, preferably one that is a precise size, such as 1GB, and measure how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use wireshark too:

> 1 - GO to the site you want to download/copy something from e.g. //F:/someFile.iso ,         using Robocopy or xcopy in windows
>
> 2 - Start the packet capture(without filters)
>
> 3 - Start downloading
>
> 4 - When finished, go to the network flow pacture, if you se packet 
>       belonging to it, right click it and set a conversation filter (ip/tcp).
>
> 5 - Choose statistics - protocol hirarchy.
>
> 6 - Or choose statistics - IOgraphs
>
> 7 - There you might set more things

Comment: This will measure the internet speed, not the speed locally. If Wifi is faster than internet, the wrong  speed is assumed.

Comment: That's right. I will edit it, to download from another IP in the same LAN within the router.